# Load Excel Data, Select Rows using a Column and then load into a list Python

Tags: python, excel, list, import

I have a python script that I use to load multiple excel workbooks (1 sheet in each workbook) into a list and then perform a sort on the data.

I would like to import the same workbooks but before loading into the list i would like to select certain rows based on content of a column.

e.g.

[image: Example Excel Sheet]

My current script loads all data in, for example I would like to only load in rows were 'A' appears in Column 3.

My current script looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid
import xlrd
params = [r'C:\Users\Desktop\Input\1.xlsx',
      r'C:\Users\Desktop\Input\2.xlsx',
              ]
data = []
for param in params:
    data.append({'file':param,
                 'id':str(uuid.uuid4()),
                 'df':pd.read_excel(param),
                       })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to read the excel file then filter it:

```
newdf = pd.read_excel(path)
newdf = newdf[newdf['C']=='A']
```

Then you can append two dataframes together:

```
olddf = olddf.append(newdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mask the dataframe by applying a function that maps a `Series` to boolean value. E.g.

```
df = pd.read_excel(path)
mask = df['some_column'].apply(lambda value: 'A' in value)
df = df[mask]
```

You can generalise this masking to operate on multiple columns by operating on the row instead

```
mask = df.apply(lambda row: 'A' in row['some_column'], axis=1)
df = df[mask]
```

Both of these would achieve the same thing.